# Painting Aluminum Window Trim a new color? Primer? Then Paint?

Tags: paint, repainting

What is the process of repainting aluminum window trim that already has a coat of paint on it?

The house has aluminum trim around the windows and the previous owner painted it a darker color. I'd like to return it back to white. Since its already painted should I just scuff up and put 1-2 coats of paint on top? Or would it be better to do 1 coat of primer, and then 1 coat of paint?

No peeling and it looks adhered everywhere, its just an awful color I want gone.

Wipe with a TSP substitute beforehand? Scuff sand quickly?

What are suitable exterior primers and paint types to use for? Urethane enamel, or an Acrylic latex?

Comment: Turning back to white colour, will probably take primer and a few coats of paint, especially if a dark colour.

Answer (score -1):

The best paint for your aluminum is a satin or eggshell type of paint that will provide the best results for longevity, and it will hold the finish longer. Did you know that Cleaning and stain-resistant are two of the many advantages of satin or eggshell paint.

Furthermore, Aluminum trims are standard for older homes and have recently been trending down within interior/exterior design. However, you can still paint aluminum trim. The process is very similar to painting vinyl trims.

Steps for painting

Thoroughly clean the aluminum and let dry. Sand the metal surface with coarse-, then fine-grit sandpaper. Apply self-etching primer, let dry, then sand again. Apply paint (multiple coats, and sanding between coats, may be necessary).

Comment: There's  a lot of "copy and paste" in here without giving credit to the original writers.

Comment: Seems to be a bit of a habit